# The width of sections in angular gantt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gantt-chart, angular-gantt

I'm not able to use gantt.section. You can see the picture below that the width of the section is zero, it seems that I miss some files. I imported in my html file :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/angular-gantt/dist/angular-gantt.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=node_modules/angular-gantt/dist/angular-gantt-plugins.css"/> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/angular-gantt/dist/angular-gantt-core.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/angular-ui-tree/dist/angular-ui-tree.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/angular-gantt/src/plugins/sections/sections.css" />
```

All the plugins that I use work fine except sections. 
data:

```
[
              {
                "name": "Create concept",
                "tasks": [
                  {
                    "name": "Create concept",
                    "priority": 20,
                    "content": "<i class=\"fa fa-cog\" ng-click=\"scope.handleTaskIconClick(task.model)\"></i> {{task.model.name}}",
                    "color": "#F1C232",
                    "from": moment(1568800800000),
                    "to": moment(1568808000000),
                    "progress": 100,
                    "sections": {
                      "items": [
                        {
                          "name": "Section #1",
                          "classes": [
                            "section-1"
                          ],
                          "from": moment(1568800800000),
                          "to": moment(1568811600000)
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "Section #2",
                          "classes": [
                            "section-2"
                          ],
                          "from": moment(1568811600000),
                          "to": moment(1568808000000)
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "id": "10c452b2-618b-f694-b0b6-b33ebfaac4fb"
                  }
                ],
                "id": "1477337d-0c9a-0174-2d08-b45befb0fe32"
              }
            ]
```

the html part :

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12"
                                 gantt data="data"
                                 filter-row="{'name': ganttOptions.filterRow}"
                            >
                                <gantt-tree></gantt-tree>
                                <gantt-sections disable-magnet="true"></gantt-sections>// When I leave the default disable-magnet, I find in console an error says that Cannot read property 'getMagnetDate' of undefined
                                <gantt-dependencies enabled="true" read-only="true" js-plumb-defaults="jsPlumbDefaults" fallback-endpoints="fallbackEndpoints"></gantt-dependencies>
                            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: How are you binding data to the div? The width depends on the content of the gantt.section.

Comment: Thanks @nircraft, I just edit my question